# MYSQL: Query two tables and join results from second table to an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to query my MYSQL Database -  unfortunately I'm not good at MYSQL at all...

I have two tables:

posts:

```
---------------------
| id | name | type  |
---------------------
| 1  | mike | type1 |
| 2  | john | type2 |
| 3  | bill | type1 |
---------------------
```

postmeta:

```
-------------------------------
| id | post_id | key  | value |
-------------------------------
| 1  |    1    | key1 | val1  |
| 2  |    1    | key2 | val2  |
| 3  |    3    | key3 | val3  |
-------------------------------
```

What I want is some logic like:

```
When posts.type == type 1 
select m.id, m.key, m.value from postmeta m
where post_id === posts.id
```

And best would be, if I had a $result => $row like this:

```
array (
  id => post.id,
  name => post.name,
  options => array ( 
    key => value
     ...
  )
)
```

Here is my query right now. It get's close, but doesn't do the trick yet:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.post_content, p.post_type, m.meta_key, m.post_id, m.meta_id, m.meta_value 
    FROM posts p 
    JOIN postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.id
    WHERE type='type1'
    GROUP BY p.id";
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Seb

Comment: You will not get your nested array directly from your "flat" query - but you can transform it that way very easy.

Comment: how are you currently fetching the results from your SQL query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select using an inner join and condition

```
 select m.id, m.key, m.value 
 from postmeta m
 inner join posts as p on( p.id = m.id and p.type = 1)
```

Comment: Not 100% what I wanted - but about 98% and I figured it out the rest myself. ;-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `GROUP_CONTACT()` function in SELECT query but be careful as it is length-limited and will truncate anything that goes past this limit.